# Visual Studio 2022 Debugger stepping into native C# libraries

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2022, c#-native-library

I recently upgraded my `Visual Studio 2022` to Version `17.7.4` and since then (I think), whenever I am trying to debug my application, the debugger is stepping into native `C#` library code like `StringBuilder.cs` and `DateTime.cs` etc.

So whenever it is encountering `DateTime.Now`, it goes into `DateTime.cs` and if it encounters formatted string, it is going into `String.cs`, `StringBuilderCache.cs` and `StringBuilder.cs` etc.

Am I missing anything or is it the new `Visual Studio` feature/option which I can disable?

I would really appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Thank you!

I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Project > Right Click > Properties > Open debug launch profiles UI > Select your Launch Profile > and scroll to Enable native code debugging to deselect it

Comment: I am not able to locate the Debug launch profiles UI on my project properties. The debug setting under Debugger engines: "Enable native code debugging" is already unchecked.

Please note that my project is a .net framework project and not a .net core project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve this by enabling Just my code debugging option from Tools -> Options -> Debugging General -> Enable Just My Code.

I accidently disabled it from the Visual Studio pop-up with option to disable Just My Code debugging.

[image: Just My Code Warning]

Comment: Please consider [accepting your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) as it will benefit other members who get the same or similar issues :)